# Getting an error in PowerShell ser push script running time

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

Getting an error in PowerShell ser push script running time.

Script : `dotnet sitecore ser push -i Sitecore.Items.Master`

> Error : "Execution was cancelled. This occurs when the task is killed
> or requests timeout."

Could anyone offer insights or suggestions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

please check your Sitecore instance is stable and not experiencing any network issues and also make sure you have installed proper Sitecore CLI version for Sitecore Experience Platform.

I hope, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any conflicting serialization rules, In my case there were some conflicting/duplicate serialization rules in multiple module.json files